# How to generate random integers in bge?

Tags: python, game-engine

I need to generate random integers in blender game engine using python. I don't want to use logic bricks for random generation. I just want plain python.
I'm using this to make something randomly select a sound to play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just regular old python, [randint](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.randint). Nothing special blender related for this one.

```
import random
random.randint(MinNubmer, MaxNumber)
```

---

You also could use the *[Random](http://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/logic/actuators/random.html)* actuator. (but the pure python is simpler.)